# How to tell tyescript that isNil lodash function is checking for null values

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

Morgen!.
I have the next warning issue on typescript:

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts

the solution is to check if the object is coming or no, with classic javascript I could set a condition and do it. But I am using all around the project the `isNil` function from lodash.

The issue is that typescript do not know about it and still triggering that warning.

How can I avoid it?

```
return !!(productInformation) ? ( //this works fine
    <Panel>
        <Content>
            <DetailsWrapper>
                {/* this condition trigger warnings */}
                {!isNil(productInformation.image) && !isNil(productInformation.image.url) && (
                    <LogoWrapper>
                        <Logo src={productInformation.image.url} />
                    </LogoWrapper>
                )}
```

Here at the beginning, I check if productInformation is coming. (cuz I remove the isNil function). But then I still checking object keys coming or not with isNil from lodash, but typescript does not recognize it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Related to the answer by @ValRob, here is what I would do:

```js
{!isNil(productInformation?.image?.url) && (
                    <LogoWrapper>
                        <Logo src={productInformation.image.url} />
                    </LogoWrapper>
                )}
```

Answer (score -1):

Some possible solution is add the ? before checking values from an object, like `obj?.value`

```
return (productInformation != null ) ? ( //no warning cuz typescript recognize this check.
    <Panel>
        <Content>
            <DetailsWrapper>
                {/* no need of .? check */}
                {!isNil(productInformation.image) && (
                    <LogoWrapper>
                        <Logo src={productInformation.image?.url} />
                    </LogoWrapper>
                )}
```